# Draw two factor variables on the basis how many times one factor occurs

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

I have two columns - one with week days and one with three values (positive, negative and neutral).

```
plot( overall_sentiment~ comments_created_at, data = Meteor)
```

I want a plot with weekdays on the x-axis and bars with the count of positive, count of negative and count of neutral.

Comment: Post some sample data and then we can give you some sample code!

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making an R question that folks can help with. That includes a sample of data, all necessary code, and a clear explanation of what you're trying to do and what hasn't worked. You've tagged `ggplot2`, but are using base R `plot`—which are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

You want something like this:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

Meteor %>%
  group_by(weekday) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  ggplot() + aes(x=weekday, y=n) +
  geom_col()
```

Comment: How do you know this solution will work well if we can't see anything about the data?

Comment: I answered the question as best I could with the information provided.